# Finding closure of image of operator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm working on an old exam problem: Define for $u \in C^2([-1,1])$ the operator $L$ by $[Lu](x) = - \frac{d}{dx} \left( (1-x^2) u'(x) \right)$. Set $\Omega = \{ Lu \mid u \in C^2([-1,1]) \}$. Find the topological closure of $\Omega$ in $L^2([-1,1])$.

I am given the hint that for $f \in \overline{\Omega}$, $Lu=f$ has a solution $u \in L^2([-1,1])$ when the operator $L$ is defined "weakly". But I don't really know what that means . . . The only "weak" definition I know of is the weak convergence of functionals.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A weak solution of $Lu=f$ would be a function $u \in L^2$ satisfying
$$
           (L\varphi,u) = (\varphi,f),\;\; \varphi \in\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}(-1,1),
$$
or they might require $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_0^2(-1,1)$.

Comment: Do you mean $\langle \phi, Lu \rangle = \langle \phi, f \rangle$ for all $\phi \in C_0^\infty (-1,1)$? And I still have no idea what this has to do with closure. Any help there is appreciated.

Comment: I believe my statement of a weak solution is correct. You are looking for $u$ so that the weak relation holds. Your relation would relation Lu=f without anything else, and it would require u to be in the domain of L. You find such a $u_n$ such that $Lu_n \rightarrow f$ and then showing $u_n$ converges to some $u$.

Comment: OK - i was trying to relate my idea of weak (convergence) to a weak solution. I am still working on the problem . . . will let you know of any progress.